# Does editing questions affect their position in the feed?

Tags: support, editing

I've edited a question simply to put the title in lower case, and I noticed that the question appeared atop the home page for Buddhism. Am I to understand that every time I'd edit a question, it would resurface in the question feed? Should I avoid such edits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does editing questions affect their position in the feed? Am I to understand that every time I'd edit a question, it would resurface in the question feed?

Yes, it does. It will bring it to the top of the feed.

> Should I avoid such edits?

If those edits are good and helpful, and does not misrepresent, or diverge from, the intentions of the original author of the post, then you may do so.

For e.g. corrections of spelling, grammar and formatting are always welcomed.